# mvvm friendly approach to pan/zoom gestures

Tags: wpf, windows-7, mvvm, .net-4.0, mvvm-light

My application is along the lines of a standard Bing map example where I'm essentially placing objects at defined x,y locations in the canvas and rendering them. Instead of a Bing map acting as the background on my canvas I actually have a bunch of line/path directives to draw the underlying content and need the placed objects to "stick" to this underlying content as the user pans/zooms. I'm using the mvvm framework (specifically MVVM light) and want the final solution to be mvvm-friendly but for now need to solve the issue of my objects not sticking to the underlying "map" when the user pans/translates.

My main view looks like:

```
<Canvas Margin="10" Background="AliceBlue" IsManipulationEnabled="True" ManipulationStarting="manipulatingStarting" ManipulationDelta="manipulationDelta">
    <view:MapView x:Name="viewContent">
        <view:MapView.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform/>
        </vw:MapView.RenderTransform>
    </view:MapView>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"/>
</Canvas>
```

and I've got various data templates defined for the various types of LocationViewModels (RestaurantViewModel, ParkingGarageViewModel, etc..) to render each location appropriately at the desired x, y location using their view.

right now, the code behind in my main view looks like:

```
    private void manipulatingStarting(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    // just let the user pan/translate for now
    e.Mode = System.Windows.Input.ManipulationModes.Translate;
}

private void manipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    MatrixTransform transform = viewContent.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
    if (transform != null)
    {
       Matrix matrix = transform.Matrix;
       matrix.Translate(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X,     e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);
       transform.Matrix = matrix;
       e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

this is allowing the user to pan/translate the MapView content but the objects from the ItemsControl bound to the canvas aren't moving with the user's gestures. Do I need to somehow hook up the manipulation event to update the relative (x,y) of each of the items in the ItemsControl?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<map:Map CredentialsProvider="xyz"
     NavigationVisibility="Collapsed">
<map:MapLayer>
    <map:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate1}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Shops}" />
</map:MapLayer>
<map:MapLayer>
    <map:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate2}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Theaters}" />
</map:MapLayer>
```

And a template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate1">
<Grid map:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}"
      map:MapLayer.PositionOrigin="Center"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <rb:BindingHelper.Binding>
        <rb:RelativeSourceBinding Path="ZoomLevel"
                                  TargetProperty="RenderTransform"
                                  RelativeMode="FindAncestor"
                                  AncestorType="Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Map"
                                  Converter="{StaticResource PushpinScaleTransform}" />
    </rb:BindingHelper.Binding>
    <Image Source="MyImage.png" />
```

Then in my templates I use a [RelativeSource](http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/) binding to bind to the maps ZoomLevel and a converter to calculate the scaling.  Found the scaling converter [here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/06/04/Resizing-and-Auto-Scaling-Pushpin-in-Bing-Maps-Silverlight.aspx) but ended up using the scaling logic from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/thread/62e70670-f306-4bb7-8684-549979af91c1).